# Python- how to init random function

Tags: python, function, random, python-3.x

I am a beginer python learner. I am trying to create a basic dictionary where random meaning of words will come and user have to input the correct word. I used the following method, but random doesn't work. I always get the first word first and when the last word finishes, I get infinite 'none' until I kill it. Using python 3.2

```
from random import choice


print("Welcome , let's get started")
input()

def word():
    print('Humiliate')
    a = input(':')
    while a == 'abasement':
        break
    else:
        word()
    #   --------------------------------------------------------- #



def word1():
    print('Swelling')
    a = input(':')
    while a == 'billowing':
        break
    else:
        word()
#   ------------------------------------------------------------ #


wooo = [word(),word1()]
while 1==1:
    print(choice(wooo))
```

is there any faster way of doing this and get real random? I tried classes but it seems harder than this. Also, is there any way I can make python not care about weather the input is capital letter or not?

Comment: I would restructure the code in a cleaner way. You could e.g. build a list of 2-tuples, each tuple consisting of `("question", "correct_answer")`. Then, I'd choose one of these tuples randomly and provide it to a function that is actually printing the first element in the tuple and asking for user input. By doing so you avoid writing the same code multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, I will try creating one like suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer one part of your question ("is there any way I can make python not care about weather the input is capital letter or not?"): use `some_string.lower()`:

```
>>> "foo".lower() == "foo"
True
>>> "FOO".lower() == "foo"
True
```

An this is to help you how you could improve the structure of your code:

```
import sys
from random import choice

WORDPAIRS = [('Humiliate', 'abasement'), ('Swelling', 'billowing')]

def ask():
    pair = choice(WORDPAIRS)
    while True:
        answer = raw_input("%s: " % pair[0]).lower()
        if answer == pair[1]:
            print "well done!"
            return


def main():
    try:
        while True:
            ask()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works like that:

```
$ python lulu.py 
Swelling: lol
Swelling: rofl
Swelling: billowing
well done!
Humiliate: rofl
Humiliate: Abasement
well done!
Swelling: BILLOWING
well done!
Humiliate: ^C
$
```

Comment: I never used .lower function before. How do i use it? I tried adding somewhere like this: `while a == 'Billowing'.lower():` but it doesn't do the job.

Comment: It is a string method. Just apply it to a string `s` via `s.lower()` and it returns the same string with all capital letters replaced with their lowercase counterpart. That's why `"FOO".lower()` returns `"foo"`. Keep your reference string ("billowing") in lowercase and convert the test string (user-given) to lowercase before comparing test string with reference string. By doing so, the test is not case-sensitive. Example: `a.lower() == 'billowing'`. And upvote answers that helped :-).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I am using `n = 'abAsement'.lower()
    while a == n:`

Answer (score 2):

```
wooo = [word, word1]
while 1:
    print(choice(wooo)())
```

But in any case it will print you `None`, cause both of your functions return nothing (`None`).

Comment: Thanks :) it works! I tried getting rid of none with return but it messes up the work I want the function to do.